# React Native Axios unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, axios

I am trying to make a post request using axios in my react native code.

My backend is in Node.js and I am using Postman to test it out. Here, you can see that my endpoint aip/user/login sends back a token and id for the user with the email and password specified in the body.

[image]

My React Native code is the following :

```
export default function Signin(props) {



    const [email, setEmail] = useState(''); 
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [isPasswordVisible, setIsPasswordVisible] = useState(false)

    const login = () => {
        // on teste le format de l'email
        let isEmailValid = emailRegex.test(email); 
        if (isEmailValid) {
            const user = {
                email: email,
                password: email
            }


       axios.post(`http://localhost:3002/api/user/login`, { user })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                console.log(response.data)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        else {
            alert("Email invalid")
        }
    }


    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>
                    <TextInput
                        label="Email"
                        value={email}
                        onChangeText={email => setEmail(email)}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.password}>
                        <TextInput
                            label="Password"
                            value={password}
                            onChangeText={password => setPassword(password)}
                        />
                    </View>

                    <Button mode="contained" onPress={login} style={styles.signin}> Signin</Button>
        </View>
    )
}
```

And this is the error I get. I don't even see the `console.log(response)` and the `console.log(response.data)` results. What am I doing wrong?

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: The promise that Axios returns has been rejected. So your error will be in a `catch()` handler on the promise. The error indicates that you've not created any rejection handling.

Comment: Edited my code with what I tried. I added catch() block but still same problem

Answer (score 1):

Javascript promises can either be resolved (i.e. the requested resource was successfully retrieved)  and rejected(i.e. the requested resource could not be retrieved).

The `then()` function only executes if the promise is *resolved*. Under the hood, if axios receives a response with an error code(Anything other than 2XX), then the promise will be rejected. Axios

In the case that a promise is rejected, you need to use the `catch()` callback. If you want to print the error, it should look something like the following:

```js
axios.post(`http://localhost:3002/api/user/login`, { user })
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response)
                    console.log(response.data)
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Essentially, `.then()` is not being executed because the request was unsuccessful, and a response other than 200/201/2XX was returned.

In your case, the issue is that you are passing `{user}`, where user is an object, so you are nesting the object. Remove the curly braces around user.

```js
axios.post(`http://localhost:3002/api/user/login`, user)
```

You can read more about javascript promises, `.then()`, `.catch()` and `.finally()` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Thank you but still get connection error. I updated my question so you could see

Comment: Show us the results of console.log(error) - it should be a javascript object, not the trace you have shared in your question.

Comment: The only output I get is what is shown in the last picture

Comment: I think I know the problem, I will update the end of my answer. Don't wrap {user} in curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was instead of using localhost:port for the API address, actually using an IP address of the server.

Example:

```
axios.post(`http://10.0.0.2:3002/api/user/login`, { user })
     .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        console.log(response.data)
})
```

Take a look here too:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10404

Answer (score 0):

- first

check if the request is passed to server by : log a message whene the login function is called. console.log("called")
if it called from the react native app (front)
if not called i think that you have to link the server side with the client side

---

the error "network error " refers to that problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Solution is the following:

- If you working on your smartphone , make sure to have your computer and device connected to the same Network ( Wi-fi).
- Don't use localhost , go to cmd and type ipconfig and copy the IPv4 Adress from Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi and make a call like that:
  " axios.post(`http://192.168.0.111:3002/api/user/login`, { user }) "
- You need to open the port to allow access through Windows Firewall (if you working on windows)
- If you don't know how open a port on windows firewall , click on the link or paste it on google (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMGPyZtdP00) and you will see a detailed tutorial.

I would like to make a suggestion, in the future try to use the async / await syntax (this is what I use) instead of .then (), it makes your work easier and easy to understand.